# How to sort data in search container liferay

Tags: sorting, search, liferay

How can I sort the data in liferay search container whenever I click the small icon? Ascending or Descending order. How will I achieve that? How will I add the ascending/descending function in search container?

[image: Tables]

Thank you in advance. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a sorting in liferay search container 2 ways 
1. Using liferay api
2. By implementing custom order comparator
Here is a example you can refer it has sown both examples in detail http://itsliferay.blogspot.in/2011/07/orderable-search-container.html.
hope this helps you.